# Using the Builder Pattern to returned a transformed argument

Tags: java, design-patterns, imagemagick, bufferedimage, builder

I have a script (called TextCleaner) that passes many optional flags on a text image and saves the resulting transformations as an output. However, the script is written in bash and I need it to fit into our Java stack.

So I looked around and I heard that a Builder pattern is great for optional arguments (I've used them before without even realizing it). So I'm trying to create a Builder to solve my problem but Builders only return themselves. They aren't supposed to return any other type. One person recommended I just call `.getImage()` instead of `.build()` but I'm not sure if that's proper. This is what I have now for my theoretical TextCleaner class:

```
BufferedImage img = new TextCleaner.Builder("Capture1.png")
        .convertGreyScale()
        .enhance(Enhance.STRETCH)
        .filterSize(15)
        .offset(20);
        .getImage();
```

What should I do?

EDIT: Thinking further, maybe I'm wrong in thinking the class should be `TextCleaner`. Maybe the functionality of the TextCleaner script should be implemented in a wrapper class called `BufferedImageWrapper`. That way I can call .build() and then just grab the image through some method `.getImage()`. Is this the better option?

Comment: I think in this case build is not that proper because this builder doesn't look like the builder of the real image. I'm not sure what the `TextCleaner` really is.

Comment: TextCleaner is an ImageMagick script. I'm going to cleanroom implement it into a Java class.

Comment: Consider `TextCleaner.Builder("Capture1.png")...build().getImage()`, where `build()` returns a `TextCleaner` instance, and `getImage()` returns the `BufferedImage` from the `TextCleaner`.

Comment: @AndrewS I was just thinking this! Though I was thinking of a convoluted ``BufferedImageWrapper`` class. Would your suggestion be considered good design practice? If it is, please put it as an answer and I'll choose it.

Comment: Textcleaner is my script. If you are going to be using that in a commercial environment, then you will need to license it from me. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. It is free for personal use only.

Comment: Expanding on @AndrewS's comment, I would recommend moving the "Capture1.png" input parameter to the `getImage("Capture1.png")` method. In fact, rename `getImage` to `cleanImage`. The whole point of a builder-pattern is the reuse of common user-defined options, and the input-image has no influence to the design pattern until the final _get_ `BufferedImage` is requested.

Comment: @fmw42 That's our intention. We're getting ready to email you but let's have that discussion through email.

Comment: @emcconville So ``.Builder("Capture1.png")`` and be replaced with Something like ``TextCleaner.getImage("Capture1.png").convertGreyScale()``? I was under the impression that you pass required arguments into ``.Builder()``.

Comment: More like `TextCleaner.Builder().convertGreyScale() ... .cleanImage("Capture1.png")`. The `.Builder()` is going to allocated and initialize "building" context, but it doesn't need to know about source file at this stage. Unless the source file needs to be evaluated to programmatically determine next steps (which defeats the point of the builder pattern).

Comment: @emcconville So ``.cleanImage("Capture1.png")`` will be a ``BufferedImage`` function that computes a new image that evaluates all the called methods with their passed arguments. I'm guessing the other methods will just be for fields while the ``cleanImage`` method does the actual computation. Correct?

Comment: That would be correct, but that's just my personal suggestion.

Comment: I'm considering voting to close this question here on SO, as "primarily opinion based" (the many comments and lack of answers also suggests this). I think this question would be a better fit on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @haraldK The question asks about good practice and not necessarily asking for opinions for names and structure. I think the answer is essentially "use the builder but pass a method to get the image as well". I'm just waiting for someone to write it out as a full answer.

Code Review does look like a better forum for my question though.